# How to convert string to start with capital letter

Tags: javascript

How to convert string to start with capital letter.

```
var a="rambabu";
```

I am expecting output as

```
console.log(a); // Rambabu
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var a="rambabu";
a = a.replace(/(\w)(\w*)/g,
        function(g0,g1,g2){return g1.toUpperCase() + g2.toLowerCase();});

console.log(a);
```

Comment: try  var str="Rambabu";   str.replace(/(^[a-z])|(\s+[a-z])/g, txt => txt.toUpperCase());

Comment: your suggested code is working, but if you want to get Pascal case, code will not work